# How does one do a SQL join with multiple comparisons?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

OK, so I'm using MySQL 5.16, and I'm attempting to join two very similar tables of patrons based on their ID and whether the amount of money they spent is different between the tables. I'm essentially trying to look at the amounts in table_a and find all the corresponding entries in table_b that either don't exist yet or are different.

Here is my example code:

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN
        table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
AND     table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent
```

The error I'm getting is a syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'total_spent != table_b.total_spent' at line 5
```

It's probably something obvious that I'm just missing, but nobody online that I've found has asked this specific question. The desired results of this query is a list of all the entries in table_a that either don't have a corresponding entry in table_b, or do, but that entry has a different total_spent.

EDIT:

OK, I messed up the LEFT JOIN. Here is the code now:

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN
        table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent
OR      (table_a.total_spent IS NOT NULL AND table_b.total_spent IS NULL)
OR      (table_a.total_spent IS NULL AND table_b.total_spent IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Same error. I don't think it's the operator choice.

Comment: Please paste the actual syntax error.

Comment: It's in there now. Sorry about that.

Comment: You should put the `AND` clause into your `OR` statement.  As for why you're getting the error, I don't know.  Do the columns actually exist?

Comment: Putting the AND clause into my ON statement gives the same error, but now for line 4 instead of line 5.

Comment: Is that your exact statement? Your tables are named table_a and table_b? In any case try putting backticks around everything, e.g. : `\`table_a\`.\`total_spent\``

Comment: It's not my exact statement, but I'll certainly try the backticks! EDIT: Holy cow the backticks worked.

Comment: If one of your tables or columns is named using a MySQL reserved word or contains a space or special character, make sure you backtick it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error is most likely a spelling error.  Check your table definitions.

However:

> I'm essentially trying to look at the amounts in table_a and find all
>   the corresponding entries in table_b that either don't exist yet or
>   are different.

Your query doesn't do this.

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN
        table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent
OR      (table_a.total_spent IS NOT NULL AND table_b.total_spent IS NULL)
OR      (table_a.total_spent IS NULL AND table_b.total_spent IS NOT NULL)
```

The first condition tests if both tables have a value and they're not equal.

The second condition tests if table_a has a value and table_b doesn't.  It will also test indirectly if table_b has no record at all, so adding `OR table_b IS NULL` is actually redundant.

The third condition tests if table_a is missing a value and table_b has the value.  I can't be certain if the last entry is useful for you.  It depends if `table_a.total_spent` is nullable.

You will not see any values from table_b where no record from table_a is present since you're running a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: Same exact error on the same exact line: table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent. This version does look better than what I was using, but it isn't working. And I'm pretty sure it isn't a spelling error since I'm literally copying and pasting this stuff into the commands instead of typing it in manually.

Comment: @user966111 Is `total_spent` a columns alias for something in `table_a`?  You can't do that in MySQL.  You have to use the base column name.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? table_a and table_b both have mostly the same columns. One of their common columns is total_spent. They have the same column name for that.

Comment: OK, this query worked, I just had to put backticks around everything. No, I don't know why. Ask Oracle.

Comment: @user966111 My best guess would be that one of the columns has a name that's a reserved word or name of a function or something if you could solve it by adding field identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your statement, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6fa5a/1 and it basically works. However, you will never get a result, since the `LEFT JOIN` condition `table_a.id = table_b.id` is explicitely excluded in the `WHERE` clause. This allows only records, where the `table_b` can not be linked. Therefore `table_b.total_spent` will never be available for a comparison (even with a negative result).

**Edit**

I have been fiddling a bit further. Maybe this is what you wanted: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11541d/2 ? I added a bit more useful data - different ids! - and removed the second condition of the `WHERE` clause.

Rearranged my fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9df69/2) so it can now accommodate your query in the original form:

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN
        table_b ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   table_b.id IS NULL
AND     table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent
```

And there I do not get a syntax errror (no result either, but that is explained above).

**2. Edit**

OK, that is quite a different `WHERE` clause. You can do it shorter with

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN
        table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   ifnull(table_a.total_spent,-1) != ifnull(table_b.total_spent,-1)
```

The `-1` in the `ifnull()` represents a value that should otherwise not exist as a 'legal' value, but this makes it possible to get away with just one comparison.

Comment: That was my bad. I was trying other things I saw on SE and I thought that where clause was needed. Error is still there without it, though.

EDIT: On the sqlfiddle site, I noticed that pretty much the exact command works exactly like I want it to there. Maybe my version of MySQL just has some weird quirk that MySQL 5.6 doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding the table b id null condition.

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   table_a.total_spent <> table_b.total_spent
```

Comment: Please check if this works first:
`SELECT  table_a.*
    FROM    table_a LEFT JOIN table_b   ON  table_a.id = table_b.id`

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried: `table_a.total_spent <> table_b.total_spent`

Comment: @Ram...how do you know this was not an answer? I get it...you have the answer...why not share it then dumbo....stop pretending a garbage collector...

Answer (score -1):

While I'm not actually sure of the proper syntax (I would try using "<>" or something equivalent if it did not work, I think there is a logic error. You are attempting a LEFT JOIN on the table where an ID exists; but then looking for where the ID is null. I believe the logic flaw lies in the WHERE clause; not the AND clause.

```
SELECT  table_a.*
FROM    table_a 
LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_a.id = table_b.id
WHERE   table_b.id IS NULL
AND     table_a.total_spent != table_b.total_spent
```

Just my thoughts :)
-Josh

Comment: ""<>" or something equivalent": `!=` is equivalent. This does not provide an answer to the question.